# SendGrid API from Custom Policy sends email with no subject

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using custom policy that calls SendGrid API to send mails for OTP. The API is successful in sending however the subject part does not reflect the value from the request.

[image]

This is my custom policy code that generates the JSON.

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody-Local" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="subject" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <!-- Update the template_id value with the ID of your SendGrid template. -->
        <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="d-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <!-- Todo: update the sender -->
        <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="sender@gmail.com" />
        <InputParameter Id="from.name" DataType="string" Value="Administrator" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Below is request generated from the custom policy and sent to SendGrid.

```
{
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "to": [
                {
                    "email": "someone@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "dynamic_template_data": {
                "email": "someone@gmail.com",
                "otp": "086924"
            }
        }
    ],
    "subject": "Verification code",
    "template_id": "d-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "from": {
        "email": "someone@gmail.com",
        "name": "Administrator"
    }
}
```

Is there a part that I've missed? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things to try

1. Update the TransformationClaimType for subject.

```xml
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.subject" />
```

2. Verify subject claim has a valid value. Try setting default value to inputclaim.
3. Update the subject field in send grid portal.

[image: SendGrid Template Settings]